# How to center a window with PyGObject

Tags: python, window, pygobject

I'm currently trying to center my application window, but it seems to be impossible with PyGObject (GTK+ 3). Indeed, with pyGTK, I was doing it this way:

```
window.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
```

So this time I'm trying this:

```
window.set_position(Gtk.WIN_POST_CENTER)
```

set_position seems still existing, but the Gtk.WIN_POST_CENTER constant doesn't work:

> AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Gtk' object has no attribute 'WIN_POS_CENTER'

Answer (score 20, accepted):

pydoc tells you what you need to know:

```
>>> help(window.set_position)

Help on method set_position in module gi.repository.Gtk:

set_position(*args, **kwargs) method of gi.overrides.Gtk.Window instance
    set_position(self, position:Gtk.WindowPosition)
```

`Gtk.WindowPosition` wraps the enum values, so try:

```
window.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
```

---

edit: seems that for newer versions the docstring isn't displayed by `help(window.set_position)` anymore, use `help(window)` (or `print(window.get_position.__doc__)`) instead.

Comment: help(Gtk.Window.set_position)